# webdev - swapping data within div

Tags: html, design-patterns, web, view

I'm a novice in webdev.

Terminology, phrasing, and conventions are still in the works. Without the right wording, researching my problem -- with books, Google, and SO -- was unsuccessful. Maybe the goal will make sense:

I have an outer < div > acting as a tab-based display. Within, I plan to add a scroll-able list and a 'show area' consisting of various content (images, text, apps, etc). Retrospectively, the format is similar to Outlook's and iOS' mail design.

The tabs are one category of data, the list items another. This is akin to different mail folders (e.g. Junk Mail -> mail item 3 -> display contents; Inbox -> mail item 2 -> display contents).

My concern is how to display those contents, since there is a wide range of possible selections and much substance to each. I cannot imagine hiding all but the selected < div >, which would be like hiding all mail items besides the current one.

I thought of creating local files and reading them based on item selection. Even then, I am unsure what would be effective. If it were only some text, I could easily swap the innerHTML of the displaying < div >. But would that be useful for my intention?

Overall, how would I go about this design? What are particular terms or design concepts that you may recommend for thinking about this and similar problems?

Thank you for the time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of using bootstrap and angularJS. You can input the content of the html into different html files, such as inbox.html, junkmail.html, etc.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="homeController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="showPage('inbox');">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="showPage('junkmail');">Junk Mail</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div-page name="{{currentPageName}}"></div-page>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.currentPageName = "inbox";

        $scope.showPage = function (name) {
            $scope.currentPageName = name;
        }

    }]);

    app.directive('divPage', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                    return attrs.name + '.html';
                }
            },
            template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
        };
    });
</script>
```